# Iniciar script php em background

Tags: php, linux

Tenho o arquivo envio.php e preciso que ele seja executado em background enquanto a minha aplicação é utilizada pelos usuários. 
O arquivo envio.php instância um pool de Threads que fazem envios específicos do meu sistema para o mundo.
Acredito que o SO (Linux/FreeBSD) ou até mesmo o apache tenham este tipo de suporte já implementado.

Comment: Quando esse script vai ser iniciado? Ele depende da ação do usuário? Ou sele vai ficar rodando infinitamente no servidor?

Comment: Ele irá rodar em background infinitamente.

Comment: Creio que a solução que esteja procurando é uma tarefa agendada (Cron Jobs), leia mais sobre como utilizar [aqui](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/o-que-sao-e-como-usar-as-cron-jobs) Espero que ajude.

Comment: rode ele pelo shell, com & no final e redirecione as saidas pra algum log. um cron é uma boa saída, se for coisa periódica. Rodar pelo Apache é extremamente problemático, não só pela questão do tempo limite, mas também por ocupar desnecessariamente o Apache com algo que não é pra servir páginas para o cliente.

Answer (score 2):

Tive uma necessidade muito parecida com a sua. Precisava executar uma tarefa em background, retornar a tela para o usuário, enquanto a tarefa atualizava uma tabela no banco com o andamento do processo.
Explicando um pouco a solução:

```
<?php 
exec("/usr/bin/php file.php > /dev/null &");
?>
```

Aonde o & no final faz com que ele execute em background e o "> /dev/null" joga qualquer retorno no "nada", não prendendo a requisição enquanto o script for executado.

Espero ter ajudado